# Xamarin Forms: I can't get the text from Xamarin.Forms.Editor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, editor

this is probably something really easy and i feel really stupid for having to ask for help with this but i can seem to get access to a Editors text from the CodeBehind file. I have tried numerous things and nothing worked, and i am about to blow up me computer because it drives me absolutely mad!

Please help me, i have no idea why this doesn't work because i have seen it exactly like this in other people's projects and it worked for them.

I am creating an Editor in my Page.xaml like this:

```
<Editor x:Name="desc" Placeholder="Describe your Problem"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

And i want to put the text from this Editor into a string variable in my Page.xaml.cs:

```
public string description = desc.Text;
```

But this doesn't work and i get the exception:

```
a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field or the static 
method or property Page.desc
```

Here is a screenshot of the two files:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRXCg.jpg)

Comment: first, the code in the screenshot does not match what you posted here.  `x:Text` should be `x:Name`.  Second, basic C# rules require that code be within a method - your line 27 is just floating there in the class all by itself.  You probably want that line to be inside an event handler.

Comment: @Jason yeah the x:Text was my mistake i forgot to take another screenshot after changing it to x:Name and i tried to move my c# code to a method, didn't work... But i got it to work by changing the name of the Editor, i don't understand but whatever... Thanks for your help tho :)

Answer (score 2):

@Jonathan Simon Read [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)

Editor is a control where "x:Name" is the property to set the Control unique Id/Name to access that specific control from the code behind and for other use.
"x:Text" is the property where you can get/set the text for that control. These two properties are provided for the different context.

And more over, I think you are newbie to the c#, please go through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/)

You should write the code in method or constructor based on your requirement. But variables can write any where. Please check variables and members of c#.